# Python What is 'List Slicing'

Tags: function, python-2.7, python-3.x, slice

Very simple (and potentially stupid question) 
What is 'List Slicing' in python and can someone please give an example of list slicing.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

List slicing is creating a new list containing the requested elements.

```
 a = ['spam', 'eggs', 100, 1234]
```

This means that the following slice returns a shallow copy of the list a:

```
>>> a[:]
['spam', 'eggs', 100, 1234]
```

Answer (score 0):

An example would be accessing the first three items of an array like so:

```
arr[:3]
```

There are many other examples on this page:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for the anwer!

Just one more question... how would I use this if I did not want to include the 3rd letter for example 

arr[:3] gives the output ar

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you'd use arr[:2] for just the first two letters...